# Using $filter projection with ProjectionDefinition in C#

Tags: c#, mongodb, projection

I have an application where users can follow each other, and followers are an array set on the user, so we can check if a given user id is in the followers array.

When im pulling a user i can project it out like this:

```
{
    UserName: '$UserName',
    IsFollowing : {
        $filter : {
            input : '$Followers',
            as : 'followers',
            cond : { 
                $eq : ['$$followers.UserId', ObjectId('[ID]')]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And then deserialize the result to match a view model.

Is it possible to create a filter like the above, with ProjectionDefinitions like this one?:

```
ProjectionDefinition<User> projectiondef = Builders<User>.Projection.Include('UserName');
```

The IsFollowing field is not on the user document, so i dont know how i can pull it.